# How to unbrick a samsung galaxy S5 (Softbricked no hardware keys)?

Tags: recovery-mode, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-s-5, sprint

So the phone is a S5 SM-G900P, it is stuck in the Sprint logo when booting and the volume keys are broken (power and home keys work).

Developer mode and adb weren't activated in the phone previously

What I have tried:

- adb (doesn't recognize my device)
- bought a JIG that gets me to the download mode screen
- I have flashed 3 official firmwares using odin (
  G900PVPS3CQD1_G900PSPT3CQD1_G900PVPS3CQD1_HOME.tar
  .md5
  G900PVPS3CQC1_G900PSPT3CQC1_G900PVPS3CQC1_HOME.tar
  .md5
  G900PVPU3BOK4_G900PSPT3BOK4_G900PVPU3BOK4_HOME.tar .md5).
- Tried flashing TWRP recovery via odin so i could do the factory reset without pressing keys, it gave me a pass and i was hoping that it took me to that screen after that but same story getting stuck

All the flashing goes smoothly, but like i said gets stuck in the sprint logo
   on all 3

I've read that going into recovery mode and wiping dalvik cache and cache plus factory reset fixes the stuck in carrier logo screen, but with no volume keys i can't access recovery mode.

So i'd love to hear any input or any ways you guys come across that can help me

Much appreaciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what caused the brick as it can be a hardware issue, a damaged eMMC chip for example.

However, instead of flashing one file, you should try flashing ''repair'' files which are 4 flashable files you can load individually. These files contain the full set of Samsung firmware files. Inside these packages you will get **PDA, AP, Modem, Phone, CP, BL, Bootloader, and CSC** file.

Download theme from [here](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=24438995911977181) and flash using Odin.

Fell free to ask if you encounter any problem.

Comment: well when i got the phone it didn't register the volume keys, and had android 6.0 got it to a repair shop to unlock the phone to use with a local carrier (outside the US) and then tired of the bloatware flashed a custom rom (lineage OS to be specific) when i did that the local carrier stopped working both phone calls and data plan/internet so i decided to go back to the official firmware and that's when the stuck in sprint logo happened. 

P.D: Downloading the repair firmware from the link right now

Comment: So in this case, the files should fix that. Just load everything correctly.

Comment: just checking, i downloaded the file now and is a single tar.md5 like the other ones instead of the separated ones you pointed do i proceed?

Comment: The description said 4 files.... Yes try flashing and see the result.

Comment: It worked!!!!! thank you so much! I have been trying for weeks and read all the internet. Wish i could give you thumbs up but i dont have enough reputation for that

Comment: I'm glad that I helped. :D